# How to pass different variables to same type of QML

Tags: c++, qt, variables, qml

I need to pass two different variable to same type of QML, but i did not have success. The variables are "dataTelemetry.target1Trajectory" and "dataTelemetry.target2Trajectory". The following code is a representation of a instantiation of these two same components.

```
Components.SimulatorItem {id: componentTarget1; name: "Alvo 1";}
Components.SimulatorItem {id: componentTarget2; name: "Alvo 2";}
```

In SimulatorItem i did that function to set these different variables: i took a local variable called "trajectory" and make that conditional, but i wanna set "dataTelemetry.target1Trajectory" directly. I called "setValues" in QML file who instantiate both components.

1. SimulatorItem.qml

   ```
   function setValues(targetNumber){
   trajectory = trajectoryCombo.currentIndex

   if(targetNumber == "Alvo 1"){
       dataTelemetry.target1Trajectory = trajectory
   }
   if(targetNumber == "Alvo 2"){
       dataTelemetry.target2Trajectory = trajectory
   }
   ```

What i need is set these two variables: "dataTelemetry.target1Trajectory" and "dataTelemetry.target2Trajectory" in each component SimulatorItem.

Comment: Please clarify what is "pass variable" mean, what code do you use for that and what error do you get?

Comment: i made some adjusts in text, is it more clear?

Comment: please provide [mcve], no need to explain the code in words.

Comment: Sorry, i'm beginner in here and my English is not very good. I will rewrite the question to make more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have direct control over `dataTelemetry` you can use `Binding` ([see qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html)) as such:

```
Components.SimulatorItem {id: componentTarget1}
Components.SimulatorItem {id: componentTarget2}

Binding {
    target: dataTelemetry
    property: "target1Trajectory"
    value: componentTarget1.trajectory
}    

Binding {
    target: dataTelemetry
    property: "target2Trajectory"
    value: componentTarget2.trajectory
}
```

**Update after comment**

You can also go the other direction if you like:

```
Components.SimulatorItem {
    id: componentTarget1

    //updated binding
    trajectory: dataTelemetry.target1Trajectory

    //or one-time assignment
    Component.onCompleted: {trajectory = dataTelemetry.target1Trajectory}
}
```

Comment: It's work, but these screen is one of the application and after i close all values of qml is set to default. Are there something to make the QML start with value contained in dataTelemetry.target1?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want now, so provided the two options, not sure if you might get a 'binding loop error' when using first option